# How to create Form from a Model which has a ListProperty

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am currently using Django forms with the Google App Engine and I have a model which is as follows:

```
class Menu(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    is_special = db.BooleanProperty()
    menu_items =  db.ListProperty(MenuItem)
```

I have a MenuForm which is the following:

```
class MenuForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        exclude = ['added_by','menu_items']
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    Item type MenuItem is not acceptable
```

I want to crate the form and have it omit the menu_items property as for one I don't think there is an in built control for the multiple choice, like a group of check boxes.  Either way I cannot understand with this property in the exclude items why it is throwing this error.

TIA

Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem comes well before the "create a form" task begins: `ListProperty` does *not* allow a list of model entities (although I can't find this clearly documented in the app engine docs, I'm still looking in the docs for a good, clear, unambiguous statement about that).  Try changing it into (say) a list of strings, and you'll see everything works (I believe a dropdown is what you get if you don't exclude such a property).

**Edit**: found the spot in the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#Lists) where the issue is mentioned, although it's quaintly phrased -- quoting with added emphasis:

> The list can contain values of any of
>   the **value** types supported by the
>   datastore.

...point is, you can have in the list objects of any of the *value* types... not *reference* ones, i.e., entities that are instances of some model.

Could you use a list of key strings, instead...?

Comment: Thank you, that would explain things.!! :-) Thanks for your time!

Comment: You don't need a list of key strings - db.Key is a valid value type for a list property.

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the important info -- I hadn't realized that Key was "a value type supported by the datastore" (this will let me simplify my code in a couple of spots).